# Integrating with python's quad function over multiple values using vectors (instead of for loops) with changing bounds

Tags: python, scipy, vectorization, numerical-integration, quad

I have a problem which in principle can be illustrated with the following example:

a,b and c are constants. f(x) generates my integrand.

```
def f(x,a,b,c):
    return (ax**2+bx+c)
```

I want to compute this integral from some lower limit to a fixed upper limit. But my lower limit changes. In other words, the lower limit is an array of values.

```
example lower_limit_array=np.arange(0.1,5,0.1)
upper_limit_fixed=100
```

I know that this can be done using a for loop.

Ex:
results_array=[]

```
for i in lower_limit_array:
    result,error=integrate.quad(f,i,upper_limit_fixed)
    results_array.append(result)
```

But I would like to speed this up by parallelization/vectorizaton. I think this can be achieved with  a combination of np.vectorize and either the quad function or quad_vec. I am just not sure exactly how yet. I have tried both but I get errors.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `np.vectorize` does not speed up anything - **read its docs**.  `quad` integrates one variable over a scalar pair of limits. Period!  `quad_vec` still takes scalar `a` and `b`.

Comment: You could use quad for the segments of the subdivision and then compose the results from the pieces, essentially using cumsum backwards.

Answer (score 1):

You have one function that you'd like to integrate over a number of intervals. Numerical toolboxes (like SciPy) are not meant for this use case. Fortunately, you can perform a change of variables and transform all of your functions into *one* function that operates on the same domain, say `(0, 100)`, and has vector-valued output. You can then integrate that function using `quad_vec` (or use [quadpy](https://github.com/sigma-py/quadpy/) if you need something more advanced. -- I'm the author of quadpy.)